# UpdateOrAdd method in Repository + UnitOfWork pattern

Tags: entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

Is it acceptable to add UpdateOrAdd method in Repository pattern or maybe UpdateMethod with parameter 'AddIfNoExists' ?

I want to add such method to simplify using od DataServices.

For example: Client code show data in grid..then client sends all data to UpdateMethod of repository..then Repository figures out what data was added and what data was modified.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely up to you how will the public interface of your repository look like. If you want single method for both inserting and updating you can of course expose it but you must correctly handle the behavior in method implementation - EF will not help you with it because it expects separate calls for inserts and updates.

Answer (score 0):

I always create one method in the repository which called Add, it will add new object if it's new and will update the object if it's existing but saving or updating this not belong to the repository because the repository didn’t track state and which one new or which one existing before, this is belong to the Unit of work, this why the Unit of work pattern telling that you should track of what you've changed; otherwise, that data won't be written back into the database
So you will need to add this method in the unit of work class depending on your ORM or you DAL approach
So the Unit of work will track

- New objects
- Dirty objects
- Delete object

And at the end you will

- Commit (Save)--> add new and update existing or
- Rollback